# Rename function doesn't work on XCode 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, function, rename

i am using XCode 5.1 on Mac OS X. but i have some problem that i can't press the 'Preview'button when i try to rename the variable i selected, first time it works ok, but next time i can't. because the preview button was disabled i don't know why? anybody know what's the problem?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the problem is being caused by the fact that you are telling Xcode to rename `alertTitle` to `alertTitle`. In other words, it's the same name.

Comment: OMG... I had a mistake.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Rename you must give a different name. have u tried giving different name?

Comment: OMG... I had a mistake.. Thanks :)